# CodeIgniter - Post multiple arrays to controller

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, arrays, codeigniter

I have a dynamically generated form that allows users to enter new data and edit existing data. When the form is submitted, it collates the input values and groups them according to whether they are new or not, the former being denoted by `class="new-entry"`.

So the function generates two arrays: `updateData` and `insertData`. Both arrays are of similar formats:

```
[
    0: {
        'id'    = 1,
        'value' = foo
    },
    1: {
        'id'    = 1,
        'value' = 'bar'
    },
    etc...
]
```

I am combining them into a new array object to send via ajax to the controller:

```
var postData = {
    'update_data': updateData,
    'insert_data': insertData
};
```

Then in the ajax call:

```
$.post(url, postData, function() { // some code });
```

However, in the controller, doing `print_r($this->input->post())` or `print_r($_POST)` as a test only returns `Array()`. Even `$this->input->post('update_data')` returns nothing.

How can I retrieve these arrays in the controller?

Comment: is `updateData` a JSON string? Otherwise I suggest `JSON.stringify(updateData)`. Same goes for `insertdata` of course.

Comment: I just tried your code on my localhost and it works fine.
but what I did and I don't know if your doing the same is that I used
`$('.form').serializeArray()`
you might need it!

Comment: @Johan I tried using JSON.stringify() on updateData and insertData, but the controller returned nothing at all, not even an empty array.

Comment: @mamdouhalramadan I would use serializeArray(), but I need to populate the arrays manually using data attributes tied to the inputs.

Comment: can you give an example?!

Comment: Ah, I just had to construct the data arrays as objects instead. I didn't realize JSON didn't like sending objects of arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Its not an issue with Codeigniter. Convert the array to proper JSON object (stringify) before you send.

Use

```
var postData = {
    'update_data': JSON.stringify(updateData),
    'insert_data': JSON.stringify(insertData)
};

$.post(url, postData, function() { // some code });
```

and in your controller, you can get by

```
$update_data=json_decode($this->input->post('update_data'));
$insert_data=json_decode($this->input->post('insert_data'));
```

Comment: I tried this before, but I couldn't get it to return anything.